# relationship between mood and working memory

Tags: emotion, working-memory, metacognition, mood, arousal

What is the relationship between working memory and positive or negative mood as higher order affective states which can change vary slowly compared to moment-to-moment affective responses (both valence and arousal)? Are there any literature related to this?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the community Dalek!
Emotional states can guide the actions and decisions we make in our everyday life through their influence on cognitive processes such as working memory.
I would like to share with you couple of sources ([Figueira et al., 2017](https://doi.org/10.1093/scan/nsx030) and [Baddeley, 2012](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-psych-120710-100422)) which can be quite helpful for you.

People over here tried to figure out emperically how our moods are affecting cognition processes.

### References

Baddeley, A. (2012). Working memory: theories, models, and controversies. *Annual review of psychology, 63*, 1-29. https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-psych-120710-100422

Figueira, J. S., Oliveira, L., Pereira, M. G., Pacheco, L. B., Lobo, I., Motta-Ribeiro, G. C., & David, I. A. (2017). An unpleasant emotional state reduces working memory capacity: electrophysiological evidence. *Social Cognitive and Affective Neuroscience, 12*(6), 984-992. https://doi.org/10.1093/scan/nsx030

Comment: This answer is *also* plagiarized, like another recent answer by you. **Plagiarism is not acceptable.**

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here - please include relevant information from the referenced sources to demonstrate how they answer the question.